# How to grep for something that's in an environment variable and has a forward slash?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to grep a file, and I want to get all the lines that have a certain environment variable (to be exact, `$PWD`).

Of course, using just

```
cat file | grep '/'$PWD'/'
```

is not working, since `$PWD` contains slashes.

I am trying to figure out how to do it correctly, but I come up only with weird and over-complicated solutions. What's some simple way to do this?

Comment: if you are looking for instance of `$PWD` inside a file, why add the leading and trailing `/` to search string?

Comment: that....is a good question. I thought it's necessary to have the trailing /, apparently it's not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use double quote instead of single quote, and you don't have to use `cat` (See [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)):

```
grep -F -- "$PWD" file
```

And remember that without `-F`, `$PWD` would be treated as a regular expression as opposed to a string to be looked for in the `file`.

Comment: It works, but only with removed slashes; at which point I don't need to use the quotes at all.

Comment: @KarelBílek: General, you don't. But using quotes will protect you if your variable contain special character. And you should always use double quotes when you don't want word splitting occurs.

Comment: With Stéphane's edit, this answer is the better one. Thanks to both

Comment: Why do you need to use `--` ?

Comment: @CodeGodie because `PWD`  can be set to anything

Answer (score 2):

Since forward slash is not a special character, you can use it freely:

```
grep "$PWD/" file
```

Adding the tailing / will not cause any problem. However forward slash is a special character in awk and sed. Patterns are enclosed by / /.  In this situation, you can use

```
awk -v pattern="$PWD/" '$0 ~ pattern' file
```

to avoid the awk /pattern/ {action} grammar. Here "~" is the match operator, $0 means the whole line.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `$PWD` to be treated as a regex here. So, that should be `grep -F -- "$PWD/" file` or `awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["PWD"])'`

Comment: I have to say grep -F runs faster and works in most cases, but if the dir names contains some special characters, eg: current dir is foo\nbar. grep -F "$PWD" will match the line containing foo or bar. I have tested it with (1) mkdir "`echo -e "foo\nbar"`", (2) create a file with four lines: 1. foo, 2.abc, 3. foo, 4 abc (3) grep -F "$PWD" returns line one and line three.

Comment: That's true with or without `-F`. `grep -F -- "$PWD" file` returns all the lines in `file` that contain any of the lines in `$PWD`. `grep -- "$PWD" file` return all the lines in `file` that match any of the regexps in `$PWD` (newline separated).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas You are right. Missing -F option brings a lot of problems, esp. when dir names have + ? { etc chars.